Module with two conditions isn't correct
I am trying to divide a country into rectangles in order to integrate over these simpler regions. From a previous post, I am able to use quadtree to divide the country into many small rectangles, over so many iterations. I then check which rectangles can be merged together to make a new rectangle that still lies within the country. This is to reduce the total number of rectangles in this approximation. Below is my code to do so, and it works.
Poly = 
  First@Cases[
    Entity["Country", "France"][
     EntityProperty["Country", "Shape"]], _Polygon, Infinity];
Polygoncoords = PolygonCoordinates[Poly];
initialbox = BoundingRegion[Polygoncoords, "MinRectangle"];

RefineRectangle[rect_Rectangle] := 
  Rectangle @@@ 
   Tuples[{MeshCoordinates[MeshRegion[rect]], {RegionCentroid[rect]}}];

KeepDropRefine1[region_?RegionQ][poly_Rectangle] := 
  Which[RegionWithin[region, poly], poly, 
   RegionDisjoint[region, poly], Nothing, True, 
   Splice[RefineRectangle[poly]]];



 result = FixedPoint[Map[KeepDropRefine1[Poly]], {initialbox}, 4];
 Length@result


Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, White}], result}]

MergeableQ[rect1_Rectangle, rect2_Rectangle] := 
 Area[RegionDifference[BoundingRegion[RegionUnion[rect1, rect2]], 
    DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[rect1, rect2]]]] == 0

findFirstPair[list_, condition_] := 
 Module[{n = Length[list], result = None}, 
  Do[If[condition[list[[i]], list[[j]]], 
    result = {list[[i]], list[[j]]};
    Return[result, Module]], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}];
  result]

f = Function[CR, 
   Module[{pairTM, MGD}, 
    pairTM = findFirstPair[CR, MergeableQ];
    If[pairTM === {}, CR, MGD = BoundingRegion[RegionUnion @@ pairTM]];
    DeleteCases[CR, Alternatives @@ pairTM]~Join~{MGD}]];

MergeFoundQ[
  list_] := ! (findFirstPair[list, MergeableQ] === 
    None)

merged = NestWhile[f, result, MergeFoundQ];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, White}], merged}]

The issue is that my MergeableQ is much slower than the built in RegionDisjoint, which would be a good 'first check' for my condition. That is to say, when searching all rectangles in the list to find the first pair that are 'mergeable', I would like to first check if the two rectangles are False under RegionDisjoint, so as to not waste time. My attempt is below
findFirstPair2[list_, con1_, con2_] := 
 Module[{n = Length[list], res = None}, 
  Do[If[con2[list[[i]], list[[j]]], Return[res, Module], 
    If[con1[list[[i]], list[[j]]], res = {list[[i]], list[[j]]}, 
     Return[res, Module]]], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}]; res]

f = Function[CR, 
   Module[{pairTM, MGD}, 
    pairTM = findFirstPair2[CR, MergeableQ, RegionDisjoint];
    If[pairTM === {}, CR, MGD = BoundingRegion[RegionUnion @@ pairTM]];
    DeleteCases[CR, Alternatives @@ pairTM]~Join~{MGD}]];

MergeFoundQ[
  list_] := ! (findFirstPair2[list, MergeableQ, RegionDisjoint] === 
    None)

merged = 
  NestWhile[f, result, MergeFoundQ];

The issue with my attempt is that when you run findFirstPair[merged,MergableQ], do not get None. My findFirstPair2 function is missing many candidates. What is the issue with my module?

You are returning as soon as you find a pair that flunks the second condition. Change the Reurn[...] to Continue[] and see if that helps.

Also there is the problem of res = {list[[i]], list[[j]]},       Return[res, Module]]] when instead you need a semicolon separating them. Makes a big difference, to the If[].
